# How to disable Android Jetpack in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

Following dialog box we can see while creating new Android Project.

[image]

Now whenever I am creating New Android Application, by default it is adding `androidx` (Jetpack) in Project. At present I do not want to use JetPack in my Android Project.

Can any one please help me, how can I de-select "Use androidx.x" artifacts check box as it is showing me as disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Found answer my self.

I went to settings -> Android SDK

- Unintall `Android SDK Platform 29`
- Unintall all SDK tool related to `29.x.x`

Now that check box is enable.

[image]

I know that from `Reflector` menu's `Migrate App to AppCompact` option helps us to rollback androidx package, but I wanted to do it when I am creating an new Application.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs suggest that jetify Reverse mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) helps reverse all AndroidX apis.

Comment: true,  but I wanted to do it when I am creating an new Application. Please read last line of my answer.